# Querying through four models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My relationships are set up like this:

A `Project` `has_many` documents

A `Document` `has_one` content_body

`ContentBody` `has_many` audits

I need to retrieve the Audits having only a project id in a descending order.

Comment: Use indirect associations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
class Audit
  belongs_to :content_body
end
class ContentBody
  belongs_to :document
end
class Document
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Then

```
@audits = Audit.joins(content_body: { document: :project })
            .where(projects: {id: some_id })
            .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Or

```
@audits = Audit.joins(content_body: :document)
            .where(documents: {project_id: some_id })
            .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Should do the trick. As for the order you did not specify what column exactly descending should be based on so I assumed `created_at`